# Linear Regression overfitting

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I'm pursuing course 2 on this coursera course on linear regression (https://www.coursera.org/specializations/machine-learning)

I've solved the training using graphlab but wanted to try out sklearn for the experience and learning. I'm using sklearn and pandas for this.

The model overfits on the data. How can I fix this? This is the code.

These are the coefficients i'm getting.

[ -3.33628603e-13 1.00000000e+00]

```
poly1_data = polynomial_dataframe(sales["sqft_living"], 1)
poly1_data["price"] = sales["price"]
model1 = LinearRegression()
model1.fit(poly1_data, sales["price"])
print(model1.coef_)
plt.plot(poly1_data['power_1'], poly1_data['price'], '.',poly1_data['power_1'], model1.predict(poly1_data),'-')
plt.show()
```

The plotted line is like this. As you see it connects every data point.
[image]
and this is the plot of the input data
[image]

Comment: Maybe you would like to  ask your question on stats.stackexchange as it is not really a programming question.
Avoiding to avoid overfit in linear regression a loss function is often used, take a look at Ridge or lasso regression.
Finally, if you have a perfect correlation between your training and test sets I'd suggest to check if your not actuallay using the same data for both ;)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, will move my question there. Also, I am only trying to plot the line from the coefficients from the trained model. But the line that is created isn't even a straight line. How does this happen? Given just an intercept and a slope.

Comment: Please make a separate question for this, stating the code you used, a capture of what you get and how it differs from the expected results.
I (and plenty of other people) would be happy to help !

Comment: You've provided very little context, here. "The model overfits the data." How do you know that?

Comment: @not_a_robot sorry about that. Updated with an image of the plotted line and data points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't even call this overfit. I'd say you aren't doing what you think you should be doing. In particular, you forgot to add a column of 1's to your design matrix, X. For example:

```
# generate some univariate data
x = np.arange(100)
y = 2*x + x*np.random.normal(0,1,100)
df = pd.DataFrame([x,y]).T
df.columns = ['x','y']
```

You're doing the following:

```
model1 = LinearRegression()
X = df["x"].values.reshape(1,-1)[0]  # reshaping data
y = df["y"].values.reshape(1,-1)[0]
model1.fit(X,y)
```

Which leads to:

```
plt.plot(df['x'].values, df['y'].values,'.')
plt.plot(X[0], model1.predict(X)[0],'-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Instead, you want to add a column of 1's to your design matrix (X):

```
X = np.column_stack([np.ones(len(df['x'])),df["x"].values.reshape(1,-1)[0]])
y = df["y"].values.reshape(1,-1)
model1.fit(X,y)
```

And (after some reshaping) you get:

```
plt.plot(df['x'].values, df['y'].values,'.')
plt.plot(df['x'].values, model1.predict(X),'-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this was an excercise I was trying to complete since i've only just started with regression. I see where i went wrong.